# How to correctly code an interchange data between server-side and client-side using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, fetch, tabulator

I work on a web application and need to incorporate editable tables in an HTML page. Found awesome JS tool "Tabulator", however, faced with lack of my basic fundamental knowledge in data transferring from server to client and back. Well, get to the point. 
On server-side:

- Node.js file, let say `app.js`
- required data is stored in Mongo DB in two collections, User and Resource

On client-side:

- HTML file `stat.html` to embedded two Tabulator's table
- JS file `table.js`

=== Stage 1. Send data from server to client ===

Step 1. `app.js` pulls data from Mongo DB and sends it to `table.js`

```
//=== render stat.html page ===//
router.get('/stat', (req,res)=>{
    res.render('stat');
});

//=== pull user data from mongo and send it to table.js ===//
router.get('/stat', (req,res) => {
    User.find({}, (err, users) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(users);
    });
});

//=== pull resource data from mongoand send it to table.js ===//
router.get('/stat', (req,res) => {
    Resource.find({}, (err, resources) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(resources);
    });
});
```

Here I've got several questions:

1. Question #1. Do I do it right?
2. Question #2. Is it possible to render the page and send data to client JS in one route? I tried but got an error.
3. Question #3. The output from mongoose `Collection.find` is in JSON format and it's what Tabulator needs. Do I need to manipulate it anyhow before sending it to the client-side? For instance use `JSON.stringify`
4. Question #4. Is there any way to check if data is actually sending?
5. Question #5. I need to send two different JSONs for different tables. If they are sent in one route how to separate one from the other on the client-side? I was thinking to use different paths, like `/stat/user` and `/stat/resource` but then how to trigger them?

Step 2. On the client-side `table.js` file receives data and feeds it to Tabulator tables. Tabulator has its own option to request remote data `ajaxURL`

```
//setup user table
var table = new Tabulator('#user-table',{
    ajaxURL:"stat/user",
});

//setup resource table
var table = new Tabulator('#resource-table',{
    ajaxURL:"stat/resource",
});
```

Questions:

6. Question #6. Since there're two tables on the page I need to use two different URLs. And this brings back to Question #5. How to trigger these paths when rendering the page
7. Question #7. Assuming that there's no `ajaxURL` how data can be read in `table.js`? I tried Fetch API but with no success.

Fetch request in `table.js`

```
fetch('/stat/user', {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(users)
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(function(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
        console.log('got data: ', response.users);
    }
    throw new Error('Request failed.');
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Stage 2 was meant to be about sending data back from the client to the server. But I think this is already overwhelming and perhaps it'd better put this part aside for a while.
I know there are a ton of articles on the internet, questions in StackOverflow regarding this subject, and read many of them but still haven't grasped it, and so please do not suggest something like the MDN manual.
I'll be very thankful for any help.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted out by myself. Special thanks to @jonrsharpe.
If anyone needs help on this subject, I'll be glad to help.